# Are the bit-changing frequencies in a binary sequence related to the dft of that sequence?

Tags: discrete-signals

I work with binary a lot, and I've always noticed that an incrementing binary sequence has sub-frequencies in the columns:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

So columnwise, that's `01010101`, `00110011`, `00001111`

So these three columns could be considered to be 3 separate sequences of their own. The only difference is the scaling (each column is a different power of 2). These also are all the harmonics in a 8-long sequence.

From this I concluded that a sawtooth wave should have a dft of all bins, with descending heights. I tried it in octave (this is a fft):

[image]

This sort of looks as expected. I would guess bin 5 is the 2^2 column (lowest frequency, highest amplitude), 6 is the 2^1 column and 7 is 2^0 column.

So then I was like, well, what does a sinusoid look like in binary. Because that's only one changing  frequency. So I made a binary sequence in octave:

```
0000
0011
0101
0110
0110
0100
0000
1101
1010
1001
1001
1011
1110
```

So it looks sort-of sin ish. But it's still a whole bunch of different frequencies, I assume because it's a discrete sequence. It's still not obvious.

Is it some kind of established property that the columns in a binary sequence are related to the dft of that sequence? or does the sawtooth just happen to work like that coincidentally?

Comment: I'm short on time right now, but: google "square wave dft", maybe that helps :)

Comment: I actually dont get, how you obtain the image from your first sequence of numbers. Also, how does the last sequence describe a sinusoud? Your questions sounds interesting, but I dont really understand what you did and what you want to analyze here.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I did an fft of [0:7] in octave : `stem(abs(fftshift(fft(0:7))))` I created the sinusoid by creating sinusoid vector `floor(7*sin(0:0.5:10))` and converting it to twos compliment binary. I just found it interesting that the sawtooth has all harmonics of the sequence in the binary columns and was wondering if that was coincidental or not.